# How can I build an embed link dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website that allows people to create a private chat room and share it.

I need to somehow create an embed link dynamically using jQuery. What is the simplest method to do so?

For example:

I have a form that has multiple check boxes, inputs, selects etc.

Name: My Chatroom
Topic: Welcome to My Chatroom
Limit: 10

and once the user has entered these options and hit a button it generates a link for them to embed in to their site. Based on the above options it would generate

```
http://www.eg.com/embed.php?name=My%20Chatroom&topic=Welcome%20to%20My%20Chatroom&limit=10
```

I want to do it without reloading the page if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic rundown of how to build HTML elements with jQuery:

```
var myEmbed = $("<embed></embed>"); // create an embed element
myEmbed.attr("someAttr", "someValue"); // set an attribute
$("body").append(myEmbed); // add your element to the DOM
```

From that code, you should be able to write your code to create an embed element with all the attributes and stuff you need for your specific use case. You'll probably also need to build your URL by putting together the values of the inputs -- you can access those like this:

```
var chatroomTitle = $("input#chatroomTitle").val();
```